# Usar INNER JOIN com cláusulas WHERE

Tags: mysql, mariadb, inner-join

Galera, estou remontando um sistema antes em ASP agora em PHP já com banco de dados carregado e montado, porém estou precisando fazer alguns filtros onde preciso buscar dados de pelo menos 3 tabelas diferentes e talvez mais futuramente (Mas vou revisar esse banco pois provavelmente vai ficar muita carga pro servidor).

Montei essa estrutura, mas parece que meu WHERE não funciona corretamente, na verdade, imagino que eu não estou aplicando corretamente. O que fiz:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_despesas
INNER JOIN tb_contas ON tb_despesas.id_condominio = tb_contas.id_condominio
INNER JOIN tb_contrato_aluguel ON tb_despesas.id_condominio = tb_contrato_aluguel.id_condominio
WHERE (tb_despesas.id_condominio = 17 AND tb_despesas.mes = 11 AND tb_despesas.ano = 2018)
LIMIT 10
```

Eu preciso pegar da tabela `tb_despesas`, os lançamentos de contas referentes ao `mes` 11 e `ano` 2018 por exemplo referentes ao condominio com id `17`.
Mas preciso pegar por exemplo o valor de um campo chamado `aluguel` que está dentro de tb_contrato_aluguel, também preciso pegar o nome das contas que estão em `tb_contas`.

Mas essa busca que faço não usa a cláusula do WHERE. E traz milhares de resultados meio que repetindo os valores da `tb_despesas` em outras tabelas.

Uma forma de exemplificar melhor. Atualmente minha tb_despesas tem apenas 2 contas para esse mes 11. Ou seja eu deveria apenas buscar nas outras tabelas, os nomes de contas e o aluguel referentes à estas duas contas e parar aqui. 
Apliquei um limit 10 apenas para ver quantos a mais retornou.
E ficou mais ou menos assim o retorno (Tentei extrair pelo navicat)

[Conteúdo retornado pela query](https://jsfiddle.net/ja3qotc7/)

Qual seria a lógica correta a seguir? Aparentemente estou usando o WHERE de forma incorreta, ou os INNER JOIN de forma que não consigo aplicar minhas condições.

Valeu desde já galera.

Comment: a questão é que quando você faz o inner join ele traz todas as linhas da outra tabela por isso aparece mais linhas. se você fizer um select em tb_contas  com id = 17 vai ver que tem varias linas para esse id

Comment: Isso é verdade. Mas achava que só iria trazer resultados a partir do "parametro" do WHERE.  Pensei em fazer isso pelo PHP, fazer uma busca primeiro em `tb_despesas` e pra cada resultado fazia uma nova busca no banco. Porém no final do código to com medo de ficar muito pesado.